# How to throw an exception properly when do Flux processing?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Existing code that I have:

```
private Flux<Integer> testGetFluxTestData() {
    return Flux.just(new TestData(1), new TestData(2))
            .collectList()
            .map(list -> list.stream()
                    .map(TestData::getId)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()))
            .flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable);
}
```

I want to enrich existing code and throw an exception when some not allowed data received, I made the following changes:

```
    private Flux<Integer> testGetFluxTestData2() {
        return Flux.just(new TestData(1), new TestData(2))
                .collectList()
                .map(list -> {
                    return !list.contains(new TestData(1)) ?
                            list.stream()
                                    .map(TestData::getId)
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList()) :
                            Flux.error(new IllegalTestDataException("illegal test data 1"));
                })
                .flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable);
    }
```

but my implementation even noncompilable due to the following line:

```
Flux.error(new IllegalTestDataException("illegal test data 1"));
```

Could you please suggest, how to handle exception throwing for my particular scenario?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct way of throwing exceptions with Reactor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53595420/correct-way-of-throwing-exceptions-with-reactor)

Comment: If it doesn't compile, what is the compilation error?

Comment: @OlehDokuka no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to `map` from a `List<TestData>` to either a `List<Integer>` or a `Flux<?>` (error), which makes the desired result type ambiguous. Returning a reactive type in a mapping function is generally not desired (you'd want to do that in a flatmapping function).

(side note: even if you were in a `flatMap`, it wouldn't work either because at that point you're in `Mono` API due to `collectList`, so `Mono.flatMap` expects a `Mono` result to the `Function`).

Note that the `map` operator catches exceptions from the lambda and turn them into an `onError` signal, so technically you could replace the `Flux.error` with a `throw`.

Otherwise, you'd need to turn the `map` into a `flatMap` and the `Flux.error` into a `Mono.error`, for the reasons stated above.