# Is there a way to tell when Spring WebClient encounters a connection failure?

Tags: java, spring, timeout, webclient

I'm trying to catch TCP/IP connection resets and read timeouts when using WebClient. WebClient seems to convert these to an HTTP status. Is there a way of working out when these have occurred?

Comment: “WebClient seems to convert these to an HTTP status” - typically which http status do you receive in a response when the connection is interrupted?

Comment: I'm getting 404.

Comment: A 404 is definitely not a connection issue. The request has made its way to the server. The server does not have code to service the path called so responds with a 404 (not_found).

Comment: Agreed but I've made sure the server isn't listening and I still get 404. I'm wondering if it's a limitation of WebClient?

Comment: A 404 is a response from something that talks http. Do you have any sort of proxy between client and server that might return a 404 to a client when the proxy can’t reach the server.

Comment: I guess the question is - how to tell when a connection *does* fail?

Comment: I think that the answers here are a good start - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65841285/handling-connection-errors-in-spring-reactive-webclient . Just to reiterate, http errors (4xx & 5xx) are not generated by WebClient. They are returned by servers (or possibly by proxies, eg nginx)