# Exception thrown in a flatMap are ignored by onErrorResume operator

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Consider the following code:

```
@Slf4j
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class ConnectionEventsConsumerTest {

    @Test
    public void testOnErrorResume() {
        Flux.range(0, 5)
                .doOnNext(event -> log.info("Processing -  {}", event))
                .flatMap(event -> processEvent(event)
                        .doOnSuccess(result -> log.info("Processed - {}", event))
                        .onErrorResume(t -> handleError(t, event))
                )
                .doOnError(t -> log.error("Exception propagated", t))
                //.log()
                .then()
                .subscribe();
    }

    private Mono<Void> processEvent(Object object) {
        return Mono.error(() -> new RuntimeException("test"));
        //throw new RuntimeException("test");
    }
    
    private Mono<Void> handleError(Throwable throwable, Object object) {
        log.error("Processing Failed - {}", object);
        
        return Mono.empty();
    }
    
}
```

The output is completely different if the method processEvent returns a Mono.error than if it throws an Exception.

The code as it is (returning a Mono.error), I see what I expected, 300 iterations of Processing and Processins Failed, and I see no Exception propagated.

> 17:33:19.853 [main] INFO
> com.playtika.services.catforce.pvp.service.kafka.connection.ConnectionEventsConsumerTest
>
> - Processing -  0 17:33:19.864 [main] ERROR com.playtika.services.catforce.pvp.service.kafka.connection.ConnectionEventsConsumerTest
> - Processing Failed - 0 17:33:19.865 [main] INFO  com.playtika.services.catforce.pvp.service.kafka.connection.ConnectionEventsConsumerTest
> - Processing -  1 17:33:19.866 [main] ERROR com.playtika.services.catforce.pvp.service.kafka.connection.ConnectionEventsConsumerTest
> - Processing Failed - 1 17:33:19.866 [main] INFO  com.playtika.services.catforce.pvp.service.kafka.connection.ConnectionEventsConsumerTest
> - Processing -  2 17:33:19.866 [main] ERROR com.playtika.services.catforce.pvp.service.kafka.connection.ConnectionEventsConsumerTest
> - Processing Failed - 2 17:33:19.866 [main] INFO  com.playtika.services.catforce.pvp.service.kafka.connection.ConnectionEventsConsumerTest
> - Processing -  3 17:33:19.866 [main] ERROR com.playtika.services.catforce.pvp.service.kafka.connection.ConnectionEventsConsumerTest
> - Processing Failed - 3 17:33:19.866 [main] INFO  com.playtika.services.catforce.pvp.service.kafka.connection.ConnectionEventsConsumerTest
> - Processing -  4 17:33:19.866 [main] ERROR com.playtika.services.catforce.pvp.service.kafka.connection.ConnectionEventsConsumerTest
> - Processing Failed - 4

On the other hand, if I uncomment the throw, I see a single item from the Flux being processed, I do not see the message from handleError and I see the "Exception Propagated"

> 17:35:53.950 [main] INFO
> com.playtika.services.catforce.pvp.service.kafka.connection.ConnectionEventsConsumerTest
>
> - Processing -  0 17:35:53.968 [main] ERROR com.playtika.services.catforce.pvp.service.kafka.connection.ConnectionEventsConsumerTest
> - Exception propagated java.lang.RuntimeException: test

If this is by design, what are the best practices for the flatMap? On easy solution that comes to mind is to surround th content of the flatMap by a try-catch to wrap the exception in a Mono.error. While it works, it is inelegant and too manual, likely to be forgotten.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct way of throwing exceptions with Reactor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53595420/correct-way-of-throwing-exceptions-with-reactor) I think it has great explanation

Comment: I did read this post before posting that question, when I was investigating. Unfortunately, I do not think it helps much. My interpretation of that post is basically that it can be summarized as: Don't use exceptions, work with Mono.error. This is already what we are doing, but by definition, exceptions can be thrown from anywhere and saying don't use exceptions is unrealistic.

Comment: Got it. I will have a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A method creating/returning a `Mono` should not throw exception in such way. Since the exception is thrown before `Mono` is assembled (created), the subsequent operators inside the `flatMap` can't possibly take effect since they need a `Mono` to operate on.

If you have no control over the `processEvent()` method to fix its behaviour then you can wrap it with a `Mono.defer` which will ensure that even the errors raised during the assembly period will be propagated through the `Mono` inside the `flatMap`:

```java
Flux.range(0, 5)
    .doOnNext(event -> log.info("Processing -  {}", event))
    .flatMap(event -> Mono.defer(() -> processEvent(event))
                .doOnSuccess(result -> log.info("Processed - {}", event))
                .onErrorResume(t -> handleError(t, event)))
    .doOnError(t -> log.error("Exception propagated", t))


private Mono<Void> processEvent(Object object) {
    throw new RuntimeException("test");
}
```

Note that inside other intermediate operators like `map` or `doOnNext` you are free to throw exception in the ugly way as Reactor can transform them into proper error signals since at that point a `Mono` is already in progress.