# Raise error / assert in webflux sequence?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

Let's say I have the following webflux snippet:

```
.map(str -> str.split(","))
.OnErrorResume(...)
```

I want to make sure that split returns an array of EXACTLY x items. Otherwise I want to go into the `OnErrorResume`. Is there a webflux-y way to do that? `filter` will just remove the bad items, but that isn't what I want.

Do I need to expand the `map` to something like:

```
{
  String[] arr = str.split(",");
  if (arr.length != 3)
     return Mono.error();
  return arr;
}
```

Or is there something built in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try `handle` method?

```
.map(str -> str.split(","))
.<String[]>handle((arr, sink) -> {
    if (arr.length == x)
         sink.next(arr);
    else
         sink.error(new ArrayLengthException());
   })
.onErrorResume(err -> Mono.just(...));
```

Comment: handle loses the type if you have stuff after the .handle :(.

Comment: thanks. at that point, it's cleaner to do it in the single map :). too bad there isn't something nice like a .assert(arr -> arr.length == 3) :(. closest thing is .map(arr -> assert arr.length == 3)

Comment: @SledgeHammer great idea. I think there is not, take a look at this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53595420/correct-way-of-throwing-exceptions-with-reactor) Oleh Dokuka is one of the main contributor to the project reactor and he stated all the methods for doing the job

Comment: is it really necassary to use the `handle` function and not just a `flatMap` with an if statement that returns the rresult as a mono, or a Mono.error

Comment: @Toerktumlare feel free to edit the answer