# Spring-Webflux : Print Error Response and throw exception incase of error from web client

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I am trying to log the error response that is coming from web client using `onStatus` or `exchange`.I am able to throw exception based on error code, but unable to log response.In Success scenario I can successfully log message.

Below is my Code

I tried with both `.retreive` method  and also `.exchange` method.But instead of printing response coming from client following  code is printing

**Response Printing currently;**

```
 checkpoint("Body from POST *****Printing Backend Url ******[DefaultClientResponse]")
```

**Expected Response:**

```
{errorCd:404, errorMsg:"Not Found",errorDetails"Person Not Found for Given Request"}
```

The Above Message is being returned from client, when I use postman or soapui

**Using .retrieve() Method**

```
             webClient
                .post()
                .uri(url)
                .header(ACCEPT, APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .bodyValue(request)
                .retrieve()
                .onStatus({ httpStatus -> HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND == httpStatus }, {
                    logger.info { "Client Response :${it.bodyToMono(String::class.java)}" }
                    ;Mono.error(MyCustomException))
                })
                .bodyToMono(Person::class.java)
```

**Using .exchange() Method**

```
 webClient
        .post()
        .uri(url)
        .header(ACCEPT, APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(request))
        .exchange()
        .flatMap {
                clientResponse ->
            if (clientResponse.statusCode().is4xxClientError) {
                clientResponse.body { clientHttpResponse, _ -> clientHttpResponse.body}
                logger.info { "Error Response:"+clientResponse.bodyToMono(String::class.java)}; Mono.error(MyCustomException()))
            } else clientResponse.bodyToMono(Person::class.java)
        }
```

AnyHelp Would be Appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Webflux : Webclient : Get body on error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49499545/1840146)

Comment: I used it also if u see my question using .exchnage() it's not logging body instead it's printing Client Response :checkpoint("Body from POST ****Client URL prinitng here ** [DefaultClientResponse]"

Comment: i have read your question `having trouble capture client error response` which is extremly vague.  Update your question with the current behaviour with proper log output in proper formatting, and then what the expected output should be so we actually can read it and see the problem.

Comment: Please see the edited question